# How to convert all files from gzip to xz on the fly (and recursively)?

Tags: pipe, recursive, conversion, gzip, xz

I have a directory tree with gzipped files like this:

```
basedir/a/file.dat.gz
basedir/b/file.dat.gz
basedir/c/file.dat.gz
etc.
```

How can I convert all of these from gzip to xz with a single command and without decompressing each file to disk?

The trivial two-liner with decompressing to disk looks like this:

```
find basedir/ -type f -name '*.dat.gz' -exec gzip -d {} \;
find basedir/ -type f -name '*.dat' -exec xz {} \;
```

First command could even be shorter: `gunzip -r *`

For a single file on-the-fly conversion is simple (although this doesn't replace the .gz file):

```
gzip -cd basedir/a/file.dat.gz | xz > basedir/a/file.dat.xz
```

Since gzip and xz are handling the extensions themselves I'd like to say:

```
gunzip -rc * > xz
```

I looked at `find | xargs basename -s .gz { }` a bit but didn't get a working solution.

I could write a shell script, but I feel there should be a simple solution.

---

**Edit**

Thanks for all who answered already. I know we all love 'commands that will never fail™'. So, to keep this simple:

- All subdirectories contain only numbers, letters (äöü, though), underscore and minus.
- All files are named file.dat[.n].gz, n being a positive integer
- No directory or file will have a '.gz' anywhere (other than as the final file suffix).
- This is the only content these directories contain.
- I control the naming and can restrict it if needed.

Using a simple `find -exec ...` or `ls | xargs`, is there a command to replace '.gz' in the found filename by '.xz' on the fly? Then I could write something like (pseudo):

```
find basedir/ -type f -name '*.gz' -exec [ gzip -cd {} | xz > {replace .gz by .xz} \; ]
```

Answer (score 10):

```
find . -name '*.gz' -type f -exec bash -o pipefail -Cc '
  for file do
    gunzip < "$file" | xz > "${file%.gz}.xz" && rm -f "$file"
  done' bash {} +
```

The `-C` prevents overwriting an existing file and won't follow symlinks *except* if the exiting file is a non-regular file or a link to a non-regular file, so you would not lose data unless you have for instance a `file.gz` and a `file.xz` that is a symlink to `/dev/null`. To guard against that, you could use `zsh` instead and also use the `-execdir` feature of some `find` implementations for good measure and avoid some race conditions:

```
find . -name '*.gz' -type f -execdir zsh -o pipefail -c '
  zmodload zsh/system || exit
  for file do
    gunzip < "$file" | (
      sysopen -u 1 -w -o excl -- "${file%.gz}.xz" && xz) &&
      rm -f -- "$file"
  done' zsh {} +
```

Or to clean-up `xz` files upon failed recompressions:

```
find . -name '*.gz' -type f -execdir zsh -o pipefail -c '
  zmodload zsh/system || exit
  for file do
    sysopen -u 1 -w -o excl -- "${file%.gz}.xz" &&
      if gunzip < "$file" | xz; then
        rm -f -- "$file"
      else
        rm -f -- "${file%.gz}.xz"
      fi
  done' zsh {} +
```

If you'd rather it being short, and are ready to ignore some of those potential issues,  in `zsh`, you could do

```
for f (./**/*.gz(D.)) {gunzip < $f | xz > $f:r.xz && rm -f $f}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that tomorrow. I feared it would result in a shell script rather than a simple one-liner.

Comment: @Martin, you don't have to put it in a shell script, you can run that at your prompt (even on one line if you replace some of the newlines with semi-colon). I've added a shorter zsh example.

Answer (score 2):

I like simple `for` loops...

```
for file in basedir/*/*.gz
do
    gzip -cd < "$file" | xz > "${file%%.gz}.xz"
done
```

...at least, if your directory structure is regular and simple enough. If you have to traverse to unknown depths, or additional conditions on file selection, you still have to stick with `find` or similar.

Comment: or with Bash: `shopt -s globstar; for file in basedir/**/*.dat.gz ; do ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
find basedir/ -type f -name '*.dat.gz'|while read -r line; do
 gzip -cd "$line" | xz > ${line%.gz}.xz
 rm "$line"
done
```

Comment: This would fail if any of the filenames contain a newline

Comment: Yes, you're right!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with find and parallel

```
parallel -0 'gzip -cd '{}' | xz > '{.}'.xz; rm '{}'' < <(find basedir -iname \*gz -print0)
```

Steps completed:

- recursive find all files ending in gz (case-insensitive)
- Stdin from process substitution
- parallel gzip foo.gz | xz > {foo}.xz; rm foo.gz

  - {.} removes the .gz from foo.gz (in my understanding)

Comment: I was unable to create a file called **a$(touch /tmp/could_have_been_worse)b** so I cannot test that (likely due to forward slashes). I decided to test with **block1.gz** **blo*(&%&^$ %(* %&@*()#&  %)(*#ck5.gz** and **block$(touch couldbeworse).gz**. I did encounter some "*No such file*" errors. After I replaced **gzip -cd "{}"** with **gzip -cd '{}'** this no longer occurred and I had similar .xz files. I did the same for **{.}** and the other **{}** for good measure.

Comment: @Gilles You raise good points. For fun, I changed one of the filenames to binary_garbage.gz with cp file "$(cut -b1-20 < file.gz)". This worked fine. Next I attempted each tr character (\v \t \n etc). This caused failure. I added -0 and -print0 to parallel and find. These all now *work fine*. My terminal and gui file manager are confused of course. If you can identify what will cause it to fail, let me know. However based on my testing, I think this command is *very* robust (now).

Comment: I think your parallel invocation is correct now, because parallel quotes special characters for interpolation in a shell script: With (non-ancient) parallel, unlike find or xargs, `{}` is replaced by the item with backslashes added, not by the actual item. Note that what you wrote is equivalent to `'gzip -cd '{} | xz > {.}.xz; rm {}'` — all these extra single quotes are redundant in the outer shell, and the shell executed by `parallel` doesn't have any quotes except the ones put there by `parallel` — and this is important: if you put quotes around `{}`, that conflicts with what parallel does.