# Writing to disk and compress with xz at the same time

Tags: bash, pipe, xz

I have a program that writes traces on disk and the size becomes very large. Normally, I use the following commands.

```
./run output.txt
xz output.txt
```

Can I pipe xz at the same time as output.txt is being written?

I read *[How to convert all files from gzip to xz on the fly (and recursively)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308683/how-to-convert-all-files-from-gzip-to-xz-on-the-fly-and-recursively)*, but I am not sure it applies in my case.

Comment: See if your *./run* tool can write its output to stdout instead of a file. The answer depends on that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If your `./run` will produce its output to stdout if not given a file argument (which is customary in Unix/Linux), then you can simply use:

```
./run | xz -c >output.txt.xz
```

If it needs a filename argument, but if it's fine writing to a pipe, then you can either use a special device such as `/dev/stdout` or `/dev/fd/1` (both should be equivalent), like so:

```
./run /dev/stdout | xz -c >output.txt.xz
```

Or you can use [process substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html), which is typically available in most modern shells such as bash, zsh, or ksh, which will end up using a device from `/dev/fd` behind the scenes to accomplish the same:

```
./run >(xz -c >output.txt.xz)
```

This last one also needs `./run` to be able to write to a pipe, but it should work better than the others if `./run` writes to `output.txt` *and* to stdout in its normal operation, in which case the output would get mixed up if you redirect both to stdout.

Programs are usually ok writing to a pipe, but some of them might want to seek and rewind to offsets within an output file, which is not possible in a pipe. If that's the case, then writing to a temporary file and then compressing it is probably all you can do.